# Creating a new parallel asyncio task in midstream

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio

Here's my design:

- Task 1 continually sleeps and checks for input from the user
  interface.
- Task 2 repeatedly waits for input from a temperature
  sensor.

Now here's the issue: sometimes the user may press a button that triggers an action that will take place later. Let's say I have:

```
def completion():
    # do something

async def longtask():
    asyncio.sleep(5)
    completion()
```

Now in task 1 I would like to:

```
async def task1():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        foo = check_input()
        if foo:
            notawait longtask()
        # other processing
```

Here's what I mean by **notawait**: add longtask to the queue, but don't pause task1 to wait for it. Rather, when task1 is sleeping longtask can get checked. So until the end of longtask, there will be three active tasks instead of two.

So there must be an approved method for doing this, what is it?

Comment: Any feedback please?

Comment: Any feedback please?